# Can I get an access to the thread which submitted task (and is running) for the thread of threadpool?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, thread-local

I want to override `protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) { }` of `ThreadPoolExecutor` in `MyThreadPoolExecutor`, and there I want to know which thread has submitted a task that this (`t`) thread is going to run? I want to copy over task submitting thread's threadLocals to the thread(`t`) (in threadPool) that is going to run this task.

Comment: In any design generally thread executing thread doesn't care about what thread submitted it, but if you really want it, you can saving the thread id in the task when you submit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it

```
public class MyThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    public MyThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit,
            BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, threadFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public Future<?> submit(Runnable task) {
    // get the threadLocal from current thread which is task submitting thread  
        boolean threadLocalValueFromParentThread = ThreadLocalsUtils.getThreadLocalValueForThisThread.get();

        Runnable wrappedTask = () -> {
            try {
                // set value of task submitting thread's value in whichever thread gets this runnable.
                ThreadLocalsUtils.setThreadLocalValueForThisThread(threadLocalValueFromParentThread);
                task.run();
            } finally {
                ThreadLocalsUtils.setThreadLocalValueForThisThread(false);
            }
        };
        return super.submit(wrappedTask);
    }

}
```

Comment: This will cause bugs: If we want to use an ExecutorService and submit a Runnable to it, using ThreadLocal will yield non-deterministic results – because we do not have a guarantee that every Runnable action for a given userId will be handled by the same thread every time it is executed.

Comment: Well, threadPool and threadLocal could be a deadly combo if you are not removing it when runnable is done. See the finally block above. I am setting it to false on purpose (essentially removing it) from the thread which is going to run `wrappedTask `

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-threadlocal that link explains it in more detail, using thread local its best to use user ids

Comment: Why not implementing a Runnable task which runs the logic you want, but you save the current thread id in the constructor when you create it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like this in your runnable to get the thread id its being executed in.

```
private class MyTask implements Runnable {
public void run() {
    long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    logger.debug("Thread # " + threadId + " is doing this task");
}
```

If you want to try to get a thread pool executing threads in ThreadLocal that is more tricky, best approach would be to get a access to the ThreadLocal in your runnable class.

I also read this on a site and think you might want to rethink your approach to using a custom thread pool utilizing thread local.

> If we want to use an ExecutorService and submit a Runnable to it, using ThreadLocal will yield non-deterministic results – because we do not have a guarantee that every Runnable action for a given userId will be handled by the same thread every time it is executed.

Because of that, our ThreadLocal will be shared among different userIds. That’s why we should not use a TheadLocal together with ExecutorService. It should only be used when we have full control over which thread will pick which runnable action to execute.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-threadlocal

Comment: I am submitting tasks to this threadPool from multiple places in my code. Didn't want to changes those tasks to `MyTask`. EDIT: and what @Robert said.

Comment: That gives you the thread that runs the Runnable, Sagar asked for the thread that submitted the job...